# Windows context menu "send to" EditPlus has wrong path from ClearCase Explorer

Tags: clearcase, editplus

I installed [EditPlus](https://www.editplus.com/) 5.5 (evaluation version) on Windows 10 (64 bit).

[image: About EditPlus]

During the installation I selected the option of adding *EditPlus* to the *send to* item of the Windows context menu.

The *send to* opens a file in *EditPlus* from File Explorer.

[image: Windows File Explorer]

But I get an error when I do it from [ClearCase Explorer](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.0?topic=clearcase-rational-explorer-windows)

[image: ClearCase Explorer]

This is the error.
(Note that there is no `C:\Program Files (x86)\EditPlus` folder. It doesn't exist.)

[image: Error]

This is the actual location: `C:\Program Files\EditPlus`

[image: Path to editplus.exe]

My ClearCase Explorer

[image: About ClearCase Explorer]

What do I need to do in order to send a file from ClearCase Explorer to EditPlus?

Comment: Just a guess about the cause of the problem: Is the ClearCase Explorer a 32-bit executable? According to the screen shot of the EditPlus About Box EditPlus is a 64-bit executable. Maybe this mismatch is responsible that the ClearCase Explorer tries to invoke the EditPlus executable with the wrong 32-bit-specific path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible the [ClearCase Explorer customization](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/8.0.1?topic=explorer-customizing-rational-clearcase) does not cope well with paths including spaces in them.

For testing:

- uninstall EditPlus
- install it again, in a path  *without* spaces.

Try then the `Send To / EditPlus` from the ClearCase Explorer, and see if the issue persits.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion. I removed the _EditPlus_ installation, then reinstalled in folder `C:\EditPlus`. Now the _Send to_, from _ClearCase Explorer_, opens the file in _EditPlus_.

Comment: @Abra Perfect, well done!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the CC explorer context menu customization. The file list in the CC explorer context menu picks up the "sendto" behavior from an inherited control.

I just tested this on a ClearCase 9.0.2 host and a 9.1 host.

- 9.0.2.4 (32-bit) -- error occurs.
- 9.1.0.2 (64-bit) -- Error does not occur.

Process Monitor shows that we find the sendto shortcut in the right place (%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Sendto), and the contents are correct (pointing to the 64-bit version). it also shows that CC explorer (32-bit) keeps looking in "Program Files (x86)" even though the shortcut points elsewhere. This COULD be an artifact of MFC, but I don't know...

If you can't move to 9.1.0.2, and have a support contract, please open a support case. If you move to ClearCase 9.1.0.2 and use Visual Studio, you may need a testfix as well to resolve a few issues in the integration.